# iTunes Connect - Release time if app is set to specific launch date?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

My first iPhone app is currently in "pending developer release" mode.
At what time will the app be released if I choose to release it on a specific date?

```
Via: >iTunes Connect >Select the availability date and price tier for your app. >Availability Date:
```

Will the release date be at midnight (12:01 AM) US time? (I'm in Austria, Europe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set only the date because it's impossible to release an app in a minute. From the pression of release button to effective global availability takes a few hour: there's the "preparation for the store" state which takes some minutes then your app start appearing in some stores all around the world but, if you try to get, you can get some errors then, in more or less 2-3 hours, it's stably on sale all around the world.

Same thing from prices change.

That's the history of an update of my app:

> Feb. 24, 2015 13:33      Me....      Waiting for review
>
> Mar. 03, 2015 08:35      Apple   In review
>
> Mar. 03, 2015 09:40      Apple   Preparing for App Store
>
> Mar. 03, 2015 09:45      Apple   Ready for Sale

But it took a few hours more to be effective available...

Comment: I understand but if I set the date to next Thursday - will the app be available worldwide as soon as it's Thursday (e.g.;12:01 AM) in the US or as soon as it's Thursday in each country's app store?

Comment: I've never understood this; looking at apps which monitor the store, the majority of store's changes are around 4am GMT, but it's not a rule. Normally devs which want their app free, for example, on Sunday, set app for free from Saturday to Monday. You can't promise that your app will available on 28th April at 00.01 but if you set release it will be available in that day, you can't do more...